# How valuable is the company that invents artificial intelligence?

Tags: economy, business

I have a near-future story told about the invention (right word?) of AGI. In it, the company responsible for it goes from "no one has heard of it" to billion-dollar-capitalized practically overnight. But I'm concerned this is unrealistic (it's science fiction, not economics fiction).

The process itself isn't some long slog, it's not Edison grinding away in the lab for 20 years. It's sort of a Eureka moment, and happens unexpectedly. From a business/economics perspective, what happens? I'm having trouble researching, but some of the dumb, boring crap that gets $100 million rounds of investment currently, makes me wonder if something as momentous (and universally useful) as artificial intelligence would only be valued at single digit billions.

What would that part look like at some early point (weeks to months) in the events cycle? Am I getting the details wrong?

This isn't the point of the story, but has the potential to be a plot hole if I get it wrong. Some (human) decisions won't make sense if the founder is fabulously wealthy (even on paper) 24 hours later. Sorry if I'm being vague, I don't want to give away the punchline.

Comment: It isn't the invention but what that invention does to some other factors of humanity. Look at the invention of the Cotton Gin. The initial showing to prospective investors wound up with those investors leaving and buying up as much farmland as possible as they knew that the invention would make growing cotton fabulously lucrative. Many other people stole his idea and made their own version so that the inventor didn't make anything. AGI has to have a significant impact on some aspect of industry for it to be of any value.

Comment: VTC:Too Story-Based. I thought a while about casting the vote, but sometimes the quest for "realistic" goes too far. Could this company be worth that much that quickly? Yes... if your story is crafted to make it believably so. Has any "start up" done this to date? No, but globalization is very much in its infancy. There are still huge swaths of the planet that don't benefit significantly from high technology. In other words, the problem isn't whether or not it's possible, the problem is whether or not you can come up with reasons to rationalize it. But storybuilding isn't what we do.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows, or can even imagine  the chaos AGI will inject into nearly all aspects of society. The financial and legal world will be turned upside down set on fire. Especially if it emerges as rapid as it seems in your vision.

Comment: BTW: Take a look at [ByteDance](https://hbr.org/2022/02/how-bytedance-became-the-worlds-most-valuable-startup), considered the most valuable software startup in history to date.

Comment: @JBH I think you misread my question. I can find any number of companies that go from practically nothing to (single digit) billions quickly. There's even a process (IPO) that tends to do that. I'm wondering if I'm undervaluing, not overvaluing. It goes to the story itself... the problem posed at the end only makes for a good story if it isn't easily solved by throwing boatloads of flawing cash at it.

Comment: If it's as  capable as it could be, it'd get rich playing the stock market before the company's even floated.

Comment: You're assuming that the company will still be on the market. In reality I think the first sign someone has made a really capable AI will be the entire company and all of its researchers vanishing faster than you can say "that's classified".

Comment: @JohnO I'm back to the same issue: it's too story-based. How valuable is your company? As valuable as you want it to be. You just need to develop circumstances in your story that justify the value that you want. As a business owner and past employee of Fortune 500 companies, there is no tried-and-true methodology, equation, or rationale that will guarantee any value high or low. People are fickle. People bought pet rocks. People invested in Iomega's ZIP drive. Bubbles come and go and whole libraries of books have been written trying to understand why. Why? Because you say so.

Comment: And to make a point... On the one hand, I can agree with @Gillgamesh. After separating all the "AI" hype from reality, we know so little about what "AI" will do to our planet that people might riot after your AGI's first application. As one French photographer put it, "what will people do when they no longer know what's authentic?" On the other hand, I just read in *IEEE Spectrum* of a company that slapped together a 4-exobyte computer in ten days specifically for AI applications with Saudi Arabian wealth to back him. Today, what you're asking is very volatile.

Comment: And another thing to consider is the "post AGI era." Current LLM's need constant feeding to keep up to date. What happens when that is cut off? A sudden wealth is often followed by bankruptcy.

Comment: @DavidR That would be a solid point, if my story had anything to do with LLMs. I'm always a little amazed at how I write something, and everyone else sees something I didn't put into it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not who invents something, but who makes it profitable that makes the big money.

Look at the graphical interface for computers as an example. Xerox invented it, but Job's Apple made big money out of it.

And I remember that in many start-up seminaries one of the concept that was pushed on the audience was that more than the idea, it's important how it is sold and monetized. So take care of the marketing and business people, not only of the technical ones.

Therefore in your story you can decide if the inventor goes billionaire or ends up as a hobo because they can't make money out of their idea. Either extreme is equally plausible.

Comment: `Therefore in your story you can decide if the inventor goes billionaire or ends up as a hobo because they can't make money out of their idea. Either extreme is equally plausible.` VTC:Too Story-Based

Answer (score 0):

For reference, mostly no one had heard of Open AI until a couple years ago, and it is set to soon sell shares at 86 billion USD.

Disclaimer: this is November 20, 2023. Just a few hours ago some things happened that may cause that value to completely evaporate, but it's due do mismanagement and misconduct. For the scope of this question, let's pretend those never happened.

Open AI's founder and ex-CEO Sam Altman has explicitly said his mission is to make AGI come true, so it also vibes with the question. The only thing that is really unrealistic in the setting is AGI coming from an Eureka moment. In reality AGI, if ever accomplished, will come out of decades of research and experimentation. I'm counting those decades from the beginnings of research into regular AI, starting circa the 1950's.

If you want some examples from science fiction, you could also look at the Horizon series of videogames. From outside, it looks like it's just about a red-head heroine who hunts down robotic dinosaurs. When you dive into the lore of the game, it's about a red-head heroine who hunts down robotic dinosaurs because a trillionaire had a company that taught AGI how to do war, but forgot to put a killswitch on it. The story of how Ted Faro became a trillionaire is vague, but it seems he went from billionaire to trillionaire when his team had an Eureka moment and developed AGI to fix climate change (some 20 years before having AGI destroy civilization).